# Can we delete activityHistory records in Apex?

Tags: apex

There is a need to delete ActivityHistory for contacts and related tickets for those contacts due to GDPR. I figured out how to query ActivityHistory, but seems like ActivityHistory Delete DML is not supported. but I want to get confirmation and get idea on how to delete them. thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but did you take a look at the release notes for Spring 18?
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_api_data_services_fieldaudittrail.htm

Comment: thanks. but that is field history object for sObject, seems like a different thing than activityhistory.

Answer (score 6):

[`ActivityHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm), as surfaced on the Contact and Account page layout in Salesforce Classic, is not exactly a real sObject; it is more like a view generated by the system into the Activity objects (Tasks and Events) which are in the past (Events) or closed (Tasks).

You can directly delete records in the `Task` and `Event` sObjects, which will remove the corresponding Activity History entries.

You should be aware of [Activity archiving](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm#!) in your org. Archived Activities won't show up in normal queries, but [can be queried from the API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199524&type=1) with `queryAll()` or in SOQL with `ALL ROWS`, and can be deleted.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try. one follow up question: If I query all tasks related to that contact, am I able to get all tasks including those archived ones? or I will need to do a separate queryall to get those and delete. for GDPR, we can't store any of personal info and those tasks comment are most likely contains it.

Comment: Hi Yi Tan, there's some more details in the docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199524&type=1). I'll add that link to my answer.

Comment: that is awesome.. thanks for sharing it. It seems like ALL ROWS will do the trick to get records in SOQL query. :)